# How to identify which row/rows are causing an error during a MERGE statement and why

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I am using the code below in my C# batch job to handle a large amount (20k+) of updates and inserts. However, during testing I can see that if there is an issue, such as a constraint violation, I will only get the first error message back and no information on which record (or records) it is that caused the problem.

Is there an error handling method or technique that can be achieved either using `.Net` or `T-SQL` that could give us this functionality?

**C#**

```
    private static string insertCommand =
        "INSERT (ChannelCode, DrmTerrDesc, IndDistrnId, StateCode, ZipCode, EndDate, EffectiveDate, LastUpdateId, LastUpdateDate, ErrorCodes, Status) " +
        "VALUES(Source.ChannelCode, Source.DrmTerrDesc, Source.IndDistrnId, Source.StateCode, Source.ZipCode, Source.EndDate, Source.EffectiveDate, Source.LastUpdateId, Source.LastUpdateDate, Source.ErrorCOdes, Source.Status)";

    private static string updateCommand = "UPDATE SET Target.ChannelCode = Source.ChannelCode, Target.DrmTerrDesc = Source.DrmTerrDesc, Target.IndDistrnId = Source.IndDistrnId," +
                                                "Target.StateCode = Source.StateCode, Target.ZipCode = Source.ZipCode, Target.EndDate = Source.EndDate, Target.EffectiveDate = Source.EffectiveDate," +
                                                "Target.LastUpdateId = Source.LastUpdateId, Target.LastUpdateDate = Source.LastUpdateDate, Target.ErrorCodes = Source.ErrorCodes," +
                                                "Target.Status = Source.Status ";

    public static int Update(List<ZipCodeTerritory> updates, Dictionary<object, string> errorList)
    {
        int results = 0;
        try
        {
            //Load updates into datatable
            DataTable table = LoadData(updates, true);

            //Script to create temp table
            string tmpTable =   "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ZipCodeTerritoryTemp]( " +
                                "[ChannelCode] [char](1) NOT NULL, " +
                                "[DrmTerrDesc] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL, " +
                                "[IndDistrnId] [char](3) NULL, " +
                                "[StateCode] [char](3) NOT NULL, " +
                                "[ZipCode] [char](9) NULL, " +
                                "[EndDate] [date] NOT NULL, " +
                                "[EffectiveDate] [date] NOT NULL, " +
                                "[LastUpdateId] [char](8) NULL, " +
                                "[LastUpdateDate] [date] NULL, " +
                                "[Id] [int] NULL, " +               
                                "[ErrorCodes] [varchar](255) NULL, " +
                                "[Status] [char](1) NULL)";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                //Create temp table
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(tmpTable, connection);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                try
                {

                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                    {
                        //Write to temp table
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "ZipCodeTerritoryTemp";
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);

                        //Merge changes in temp table with ZipCodeTerritory
                        string mergeSql = "merge ZipCodeTerritory as Target " +
                                          "using ZipCodeTerritoryTemp as Source " +
                                          "on " +
                                          "Target.Id = Source.Id " +
                                          "when matched then " +
                                          updateCommand +
                                          "when not matched then " +
                                          insertCommand + ";";

                        cmd.CommandText = mergeSql;
                        results = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SendEmail.ErrorMail(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //Drop temp table
                    SqlCommand final = new SqlCommand("DROP TABLE [dbo].[ZipCodeTerritoryTemp]", connection);
                    final.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendEmail.ErrorMail(ex.Message);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't determine this by executing the `MERGE` statement, you have to check for these collisions prior to executing the `MERGE`.

In other words (and I can't stress this one enough): ***always validate your inputs.***

There are two points where you can do the validation: before you bulk-copy the data to the temporary table and before you merge the temporary table into the target.  Depending on the nature of your data issues you might be able to do the bulk of your validation before the data hits the server.

There are three primary classes of problems I've generally encountered with `MERGE` statements:

1. Key collisions (duplicate rows in the source)
2. Data format errors (e.g. string representations of dates that don't translate into `DATE` correctly)
3. Constraint failures (nulls where they're not allowed, foreign key errors, etc)

The first two can generally be detected prior to pushing the data up to the server.  The third depends on the nature of your constraints... but generally we can solve these before they get to the server.

Key collisions in your data can be detected by grouping the data by the keys (`Id` in this case).  Let's assume that you have two records with the same `Id` value, but you want to merge in the one with the highest `LastUpdateDate`.  One option for this is:

```
var cleanupdates = 
    from update in updates
    group update by update.Id into grp
    select grp.OrderByDescending(u => u.LastUpdateDate).First();
```

If your constraint problems are related to null values, filter out those records that have invalid nulls using a `where` clause.  If they're related to foreign key constraints, load those keys into a list and filter on them.  You can cover a lot of the validation using LINQ queries.

The important point is that you ***do*** the validation.  Otherwise your `MERGE` will fail, and you won't know why.

Answer (score 0):

For your Merge statement you are missing one little thing

```
merge ZipCodeTerritory as Target " +
"using (SELECT * FROM ZipCodeTerritoryTemp) as Source " + --<-- need to select data
"on " +
"Target.Id = Source.Id " +
"when matched then " +
updateCommand +
"when not matched then " +
insertCommand + ";";
```

But before you go ahead with this approach <kbd>[Read This](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/)</kbd> article from Aaron Bertrand about issues with `MERGE` Statement.

I would suggest you to to use `IF EXISTS` Method something like this ...

**Update**

```sql
UPDATE T
SET  T.Col1 = S.Col1,
     T.Col2 = S.Col2,
     T.Col3 = S.Col3
FROM ZipCodeTerritory T INNER JOIN ZipCodeTerritoryTemp S
ON   T.id = S.id
```

**INSERT**

```sql
INSERT INTO ZipCodeTerritory(Col1, Col2, Col3, ....)
SELECT S.Col1, S.Col2, S.Col3, ....
FROM   ZipCodeTerritoryTemp S LEFT JOIN ZipCodeTerritory T
ON     S.ID = T.ID
WHERE  T.ID IS NULL
```

Comment: Not sure how this would solve the issue of error handling/determining which record has a problem and why. If you're using a `SqlCommand` object to execute the `UPDATE` and INSERT`s would you get that information back in an exception or something?

Comment: Adding a `select` to the `using` clause is unnecessary unless you are adding a `where` clause.  `using ZipCodeTerritoryTemp as Source` is perfectly valid.