# How to identify the row that caused an error in a merge statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, merge

How can I identify the row that caused an error in a merge statement in SQL Server due to a constraint error and remove it, in order to re-run the stored procedure and re-execute it?

I have already tried to use try/catch, but this just shows the problem, but it exits from the merge.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify which row/rows are causing an error during a MERGE statement and why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688812/how-to-identify-which-row-rows-are-causing-an-error-during-a-merge-statement-and)

Comment: i saw that question, is not the same, different problem...
why for this downvote ? i didn't found a solution in google so i ask here... can you please take off the down vote? thank you